# How to add new Array method that "doesn't trigger" for..in?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When using for..in loop along with functions I added to array.prototype, the for..in loops through all those functions as well.

[The JavaScript for/in statement loops through the properties of an object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

But how do I add to array prototype without it being triggered in the for..in?

Example code:

```
Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
    // Do something
}

for (item in myArray) {
    // Would actually loop myArray.length times + 1 for the 'sum'
}
```

I'm using a library that uses for..in loop and I can't change that.

Comment: You shouldn't, and I don't understand why you want to.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz: I shouldn't what? Use a protoype that way? Wasn't familiar with Object.defineProperty, now I am.

Comment: @webdeb: n3-line-chart

Comment: @AlexD: I'd raise a bug with the library authors, there's no excuse for using `for-in` on an array without a `hasOwnProperty` check at a minimum.

Comment: or they better should use length instead, if its allways an array, for in returns the index or the key, not the value, so it can be done less expensive -> var l = arr.length; while(!(0 > l)) {l--;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how do I add to array prototype without it being triggered in the for..in?

By adding it as a *non-enumerable* property, via [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). Non-enumerable is the default, so:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "sum", {
    value: function() {
        // ...implementation of sum
    }
});
```

...but if we wanted to be explicit, we'd have `enumerable: false`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "sum", {
    enumerable: false, // <== Not necessary, false is the default
    value: function() {
        // ...implementation of sum
    }
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "sum", {
  value: function() {
    return this.reduce(function(acc, value) {
      return acc + value;
    }, 0);
  }
});

var a = [1, 2, 3];
snippet.log("a.sum() = " + a.sum());
var key;
for (key in a) {
  snippet.log("key = " + key);
}
snippet.log("Note that 'sum' did not show up as a key");
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

All **modern** browsers support `Object.defineProperty`, which was part of the 5th edition specification released in 2009. **IE8 does not**, as it predates the specification.

---

Side note: I don't recommend using `for-in` to loop through arrays, whether you add non-entry properties to `Array.prototype` (or the array itself) or not. I recommend the various alternatives in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476). But you've said you're using a library that does it and doesn't have the necessary `hasOwnProperty` check (which makes it a poorly-written library) and can't change that, so... The above is how you add to `Array.prototype` without the additions showing up in `for-in`.

Answer (score 3):

use [Object.definePropert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)y, you can add something to `Array.prototype` while make it not `enumerable`, thus not be a target in `for-in` loop.

Though, take it as last resort, `for-in` should be avoid if possible.

```js
// This appears in for-in
Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
    // Do something
}

// This won't appears in for -in loop.
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'add', {
  value: function() {
    console.log('OOPSS');
  },
  
  // enumerable is default to false, and it decide whether the attr would be  a target
  // in for-in loop or not.
  enumerable: false
});

var myArray = [1, 2, 3];

for (item in myArray) {
  console.log(item);
    // Would actually loop myArray.length times + 1 for the 'sum'
}

// Check `add` did added to array.prototype.
myArray.add();
```